# Converting string on Array

Tags: javascript

I would like to show `console.log` if input value will be an array.

```
let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;

if (myValue instanceof Array) {
    console.log('To jest tablica');
}
```

I know that input value is a string but I can't convert it to an Array.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the value is

Comment: Array.IsArray... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp

Comment: Whatever `.value` returns, `myValue instanceof Array` will always be false as `myValue` is a string not array. Also, please provide an example where `myValue` "is" an array.

Comment: what does inputclass element contain. Can you share html for that as well

Answer (score 0):

First of all `instanceof` isn't the recommended way to check for arrays. Instead you can use

```
let myValue = document.querySelector('.inputClass').value;

if (Array.isArray(myValue)) {
    console.log('To jest tablica');
}
```

Second of all, `document.querySelector.value` won't return an array, ever. Only a string (or undefined). So you could split the string, or do a `JSON.parse()` depending on the format of `myValue` to make it an array.

If your value is something like

`["element", "element1", "element3"]`

then you can use `JSON.parse()`

If your value is something like:

`"element element1 element3"` and the expected output is `["element", "element1", "element3"]` then you can split it, by using `"element element1 element3".split(" ")`

Comment: +1 for efforts! But still want to know what is there in .inputClass element, then it will be easy to share as if how to convert it into array and then check

Answer (score 0):

## 1.1 - String is a JSON string

...you first need to parse it :

```
myValue = "[1,2,3]";
myValue = JSON.parse(myValue);
// myValue is now an array [1,2,3];
```

## 1.2 - String is a list of items separated by comas

...you should split the string :

```
myValue = "1,2,3";
myValue = myValue.split(',');
// myValue is now an array [1,2,3]
```

## 1.3 - If your need an array of chars

...you should split the string without separator char :

```
myValue = "123";
myValue = myValue.split('');
// myValue is now an array [1,2,3]
```

---

## 2 - Validation

But it has no sense to check if you got an Array, because you already know that. I asume you need to know if there is more than a single element. For that you should check the length :

```
if (myValue.length>1) {
    console.log('more than one item!');
}
```